# How to convert integer column to time column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, format, date-time

I am trying to format an integer column to a time column, but the values all end up as 12 like this:

```
12

12

12
```

[image]

Comment: Dates are stored with integers for day numbers and times as fractions of a day. If the integers represent the hour of the day, divide by 24, then format as time.

Comment: Wow that works. Care to post it as a reply, so I can accept? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to deal with division and other math to get to the decimal time value, you can use the `TIME` function which will handle it all for you:

**Usage for your example**

[image: TIME function]

MS reference: https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/TIME-function-9a5aff99-8f7d-4611-845e-747d0b8d5457

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, dates are stored with integers for day numbers (since 1900) and times as fractions of a day.

If your integers represent the hour of the day, divide them by 24, then format as time.

Comment: I really like this idea. Meanwhile, someone posted the TIME function, which I also love and find quite powerful.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of the `TIME` function, and I agree it's a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, times are stored as the fraction of a day.  Therefore, each hour is 1/24 of a day.  To convert integer hours to a time, divide the time by 24 and format as a date and/or time.

More info:

> Excel stores dates as sequential serial numbers so that they can be
>   used in calculations. By default, January 1, 1900 is serial number 1,
>   and January 1, 2008 is serial number 39448 because it is 39,447 days
>   after January 1, 1900.
>
> Numbers to the right of the decimal point in the serial number
>   represent the time; numbers to the left represent the date. For
>   example, the serial number 0.5 represents the time 12:00 noon.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337fd29-145a-4347-b2e6-20c904739c46